# Skip child to fetching of parent - JPA

Tags: java, jpa, entity-relationship, fetching-strategy

I am facing an issue where the data is getting fechted recursively. I wanted to avoid the child to fetch the parent data. Which is causing a recursive issue. 
I have mentioned the code below

Pojo Structure

```
class Parent  {
    ..
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Child> childs;

    ..
    }

class Child {
    ..
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    private Parent parent;
    ..
    }
```

Fetching the data like this

```
 `  em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createQuery("Select p from Parent p", Parent.class);
    List<Parent> parents = q.getResultList();
    // Till this point all looks good but when the code gets executed 
    parent.getChilds();
`
```

It is fetching the data like this:

```
Parent
child1
    Parent
        child2
            Parent
                child2
                    Parent
                ..
        ..
child2
..
```

Which I dont need I just want the data like this:

```
Parent1
    child1
    child2
Parent2
    child1
    child2
    child3
```

Comment: By Default default fetch mode is lazy

Comment: @soorapadman by default, fetching is lazy for to-many and eager for to-one relationships

Comment: What provider?  Lazy fetching of OneToOne/ManyToOne is provider specific and may require something more depending on your environment.  EclipseLink for instance requires weaving https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/app_dev007.htm

Answer (score 3):

While `FetchType.EAGER` is a *contract*, `FetchType.LAZY` is only a *hint*, because lazy fetching is not always possible. This may depend e.g. on the JPA provider you use as well as on its configuration. Lazy fetching is particularly problematic with to-one relationships.

If every `Child` has a `Parent`, try adding `optional=false` to your `@ManyToOne`. This *might* enable lazy fetching.

Since the `Parent` entity is already loaded into the persistence context, populating `Children.parent` shouldn't trigger queries against the database. Are you actually seeing queries being executed? How do you know `Children.parent` is being loaded? If you are accessing the value to check that fact, chances are you are actually triggering the on-demand loading yourself.

Comment: If every Child has a Parent, try adding optional=false to your @ManyToOne. This might enable lazy fetching.

It didnot work


How do you know Children.parent is being loaded?

I need to execute  parent.getChilds(); and when I am doing it I can see the parent object in it and in this parent there is a child object as so on.
you can get an idea by looking into : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_A6oOU92Jt8M2pGZlpaQ3RuQTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OK. As I said, this is not a performance issue, because the `Parent` entity is already present in the persistence context, so the `Parent` lookup for children does not hit the database. If you want lazy loading nonetheless, are you using JPA in Java SE or Java EE? For lazy loading to work with to-one relationships, you need to enable weaving (see: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/concepts/mappingintro002.htm#CEGCJEHD and the paragraph just above it)

Comment: we are having Java EE and EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872.

Yes its not an performance but the application is getting hang.
The reason is, since its a bidirectional relationship when we are fetching the child its fetching the parent as well which again set the child having a parent inside it. 
This is causing the server to hang because the circular values.

Comment: I'm not sure EclipseLink alone could cause an infinite loop here, since it would be a serious bug for a fairly common use case. Are you sure `parent.getChilds()` is the source of the problem? Can you see other methods in the stack trace (I understand you're ultimately getting a `StackOverflowError`)? The fact that you managed to inspect the value of `Parent.getChilds()` using the debugger suggests that loading children completed successfully, and the error is caused by some other code executed later on...

Comment: There is neither StackOverflowError or any other exception. The issue is it is taking time of more then 1 minute which results in our server time out. We need to get the result with in one minute of time. If we increase the server time out it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It'll work as infinite loop for hefty data. Best practice is to mention @JsonIgnore at child class column.
Thank me Later

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this problem of cyclic references, I used a **Mapper** with **MapStruct** (see [official documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/) for a quick setup) :

Then I can easily write a mapper to ignore a property like this :

```java
public interface SecondaryObjectMapper {
  @Mapping(target = "primaryObject.secondaries", ignore=true),
  SecondaryObjectDto toSecondaryObjectDto(SecondaryObject source);
}
```

and use it like this for example :

```java
repository.findAll(pageable).map(secondaryObjectMapper::toSecondaryObjectDto)
```

Answer (score 0):

To Avoid this issue , Please declare below annotation Parent & Child getter methods

```
   @JsonBackReference
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

@JsonManagedReference
    public List<Child> getChilds() {
    return childs;
    }
```

Comment: You might want to describe a little more too why this solves the issue in the question, and not just paste some code.  :)