# Fetch.lazy not working for spring boot jpa, what must be the issue?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a rest api which when called for my hotels entity, it has list of menu items which is getting called even though I have set the fetchtype for one to many annotation as lazy. Please take a look at my code in the screenshots, thank you.

[hotel entity ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeZ3w.png)

[menu item entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bNxx.png)

[rest controller endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUDf1.png)

[service method implemntation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaElI.png)

[result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmCfz.png)

even though the endpoint i called in postman ss is different, I get same result when calling the the endpoint in above images.

Also, this is the query which is getting fired when I fetch hotels --->

```
Hibernate: select menuitems0_.hotel_model_id as hotel_mo1_2_0_, menuitems0_.menu_items_m_id as menu_ite2_2_0_, menuitemli1_.m_id as m_id1_3_1_, menuitemli1_.available as availabl2_3_1_, menuitemli1_.item_name as item_nam3_3_1_, menuitemli1_.item_price as item_pri4_3_1_ from hotels_menu_items menuitems0_ inner join menu_items menuitemli1_ on menuitems0_.menu_items_m_id=menuitemli1_.m_id where menuitems0_.hotel_model_id=?
```

Comment: Please add your code as a text.

Answer (score 0):

It's might be due to a proxy call by Jackson.

Please try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51124594/10147096).